# Should my mail sending app mimic it's users domain

Tags: email, smtp, mandrill

I'm building a web app. In this web app users sign up for an account. These users use this app because it's a tool for organizing their end customers.

On of the features of this app is sending emails. Some of these mail are sent from me (the app author) to the users... And some other mails are sent on behalf of the users to their end customers.

**Regarding spam, and deliverability**, when the app is sending mails on behalf of it's users, should it mimic their company domain and senders instead of its own?

Should the `from` field be: `my-app-name <noreply@myapp.com>` or `user-name <noreply@usersdomain.com>`

I reality all mail **will** be sent from the domain `myapp.com`. The questions is if I should mimimc users domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be likely to run into problems with messages not being delivered if you attempt to send messages from other domains from your mail server, because of SPF records and DMARC policies.  Most large email providers such as Yahoo and Gmail have SPF records setup, which advise receiving mail servers to treat mail from senders at these domains as spam unless the messages are sent from mail servers within these domains.  Yahoo has even taken it a step further with a DMARC policy that they recently started - see https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us/articles/201876356-Yahoo-DMARC-Changes-Message-not-accepted-for-policy-reasons- for more info.